# GeoServer Image Mosaic Plugin error loading time-series GeoTIFFs

Tags: raster, geoserver, geotiff-tiff, image-mosaic

In an AWS EC2 Instance Linux installed with GeoServer
I am trying to load time-series raster imagery using the Image Mosaic plugin as described here:
https://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/tutorials/imagemosaic_timeseries/imagemosaic_timeseries.html

I have modified the time to -GMT and created all .properties files.

However, when I try to load the directory to publish I am getting the following error

[image: Geoserver error loading raster data in AWS ec2 linux instance]

I was checking the read write access of GeoServer to the data folder it  was okay.

Contents of -indexer.properties file:

Caching=false
TimeAttribute=ingestion
ElevationAttribute=elevation
Schema=*the_geom:Polygon,location:String,ingestion:java.util.Date,elevation:Double
PropertyCollectors=TimestampFileNameExtractorSPItimeregex,DoubleFileNameExtractorSPIelevationregex

-timeregx.properties

regex=[0-9]{8}

I do not know where it went wrong?

---

Yes in my question the *indexer.properties*  contents are not complete that was a paste error.

I have used the indexer.properties without the elevation collector as suggested. Still, it is not working.

I am attaching the log

[image]

Also the filenames I am using in valid form.

Comment: Welcome to Geographic Information Systems! Please look in the log files and add any relevant error messages to your question using the [edit] button

Comment: Could you update the question with the contents of your ,properties files? The error message you are getting could appear when the indexer.properties is present, but has errors.Try to remove indexer.properties and create the mosic. If that works, you have a problem with indexer.properties.

Answer (score 1):

After your edit its still not clear if you have succeeded in creating the mosiac without the indexer file. But unless you have lost something from your indexer file when pasting to stackexchange you indexer.propertis is malformed. Look at the example again. You are missing [] around the regex filename and the variable name inside () for each of the collectors.

**From the example:**

```
Caching=false
TimeAttribute=ingestion
ElevationAttribute=elevation
Schema=*the_geom:Polygon,location:String,ingestion:java.util.Date,elevation:Double
PropertyCollectors=TimestampFileNameExtractorSPI[timeregex](ingestion),DoubleFileNameExtractorSPI[elevationregex](elevation)
```

Also if you are not using the elevation, remove the elevation collector, otherwise you need to have a *elevationregex.properties* file as well.

**Try this file:**

```
TimeAttribute=ingestion
Schema=*the_geom:Polygon,location:String,ingestion:java.util.Date
PropertyCollectors=TimestampFileNameExtractorSPI[timeregex](ingestion)
```

And also make sure that all your filnames contains 8 digits that corresponds to a valid date on the form yyyyMMdd.